# It would be good if you could please undelete three comments on the YouTube Kids autoplay question

Tags: support, comments

There were about half a dozen comments still visible on [the YouTube Kids autoplay question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/378644/youtube-kids-is-cleaner-than-regular-youtube-sadly-i-havent-found-any-metho). I flagged just one as "no longer needed" (too chatty), but all of them got deleted.

It would be most excellent if you could please [undelete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98036/moderators-should-be-able-to-undelete-comments) three of the comments:

- The comment in which someone tested YouTube Kids for iOS and found it impossible to disable autoplay.  (This was an important comment; it deserves upvotes.)
- The second-last comment, which was about youtube.com user scripts.
- The last comment, which was about using youtube.com user scripts on youtubekids.com.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Comments are always ephemeral at best, so everyone please get answers should be in the answer Field and not in comments. I’ll see if it’s easy to salvage what’s there, but might post a screen shot and let you sort it based on how comfortable I am making a value decision on the comments.

- https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/by-site/youtube.com?site=youtube.com&q=autoplay

The rest should be taken up in chat with ankii and Allan if needed. Both of those users are well able to get up an answer and then edit it if needed or hold a chat in chat to see if they can understand what you seek.

Comment: There's no answer at all yet.  None of the comments are answers; they're just comments.  ❧  The iOS comment hinted that an answer would be challenging to find.  The final two comments are our attempts to make our way towards an answer, but are not yet themselves answers.

Comment: Comments aren't so difficult to undelete.  You may view the [undeletion instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170489), if you wish.

Comment: If you prefer, you can undelete the last ten comments, and I can then flag seven of them, in order to ask you to please re-delete just those seven.

Comment: @tealhillsupportsMonica I dumped the last few in chat. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer on how to put up non answers, showing research so that people can collaborate. An answer is anything that shows research and what doesn’t work. Answers don’t have to be complete or correct, just attempts to get closer to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since all those comments included me, I'm posting an answer.

Original comment suggested using userscripts to toggle autoplay, but I later realised that there might not be such button at all, so I provided an alternative, in an answer to your question.

I don't contend deletion of the comments, I myself often clean up after they are obsolete and flag for deletion of the rest. In this case, I just didn't get your ping since I had not visited *that* chatroom in the last 7 days. I am frequent in https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/ask-different-chat.

Now that we can talk under my answer there, that migration chatroom is useless too.